# Cryptic jigsaw crossword puzzle

Tags: cryptic-clues, cryptic-crosswords

This is a cryptic jigsaw crossword: no clue numbers are provided in the grid; solvers must instead fit the answers in wherever they can.  The solution is unique, and the green tick mark goes to whoever shows the filled grid and explains the clues (correctly) first.
Clues are listed in alphabetical order.  There will be, as you can see from the grid, more than one answer starting with the same letter, and no answers starting with other letters.  All answers can be found in Chambers dictionary (amongst other sources) but I don't think any answers are so obscure that it will matter.

Any feedback on the clues is appreciated :)

[image]

**Clues:**

- Head of research in small position after promotion is management (14)
- A timeless story upsets ardent fans (11)
- A section of certain diameter inspired confidence (7)
- Spin a plane wheel out after revolving cylinder (6,4)
- Aran coil knit into states modified by partners? (8)
- Physicist leads to departments, introducing Rutherford and colleagues (5)
- In a lowered state Rich transferred data from PC (10)
- *Le coeur ou la raison*? Which embraces French bread? (4)
- No longer quoted or stirred up (7)
- Scorching goes awry -- throw away skin of ramps for dumplings (7)
- Thrown about violently after beheading?  It might catch on… (4)
- … nevertheless, in Idaho we verify! (7)
- Jimmy, regularly tipsy, bribes those who drink (8)
- Bemused, rein in cheat regarding parental legacy (11)
- Cases of importer overburden Massimo needing eager dealer in household goods (10)
- Wight as an example is given latitude and energy (4)
- Island jumper (6)
- Keen to play in middle of leg (4)
- Ashtanga salesman embraces eastern 'pasta' type (7)
- *Compass* bar's head of mixology needing treacle cocktail with no recipe (8,6)
- Legendary cat and I wearing US headdress as record of distance travelled (10)
- Italian dish Viola cycled around Rhode Island?  On the contrary! (7)
- Renounces Frenchman's consumption of prematurely terminated zygote (7)
- Answer with reference to leaders of scientific panel on dimensions (7)
- Legendary persian bird hears of diamond (3)
- Yes, Carter organised Home Office, leader (9)
- Started tennis match second with fierce hearts against journalist (6)
- Disk I erase holds *King of the Slopes*? (5)
- Italian noodles and changes past eight… (9)
- … just a touch thanks, Duke (3)

and, for people who can't view images, the grid is given in an ASCII form below.  Dots (.) indicate cells, and * is used for black cells and the boundary.

```
*****************
*......*........*
*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*
*.......*.......*
*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*
*....*..........*
*.*.*.*.*.*.*.***
*...*...........*
*.***.*.*.*.***.*
*...........*...*
***.*.*.*.*.*.*.*
*..........*....*
*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*
*.......*.......*
*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*.*
*........*......*    
*****************
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The completed grid:

> [image]

The clues:

> Head of research in small position after promotion is **management** (14)
>   **ADMINISTRATION** - AD + MINI + R in STATION
>
>  A timeless story upsets **ardent fans** (11)
>   **AFICIONADOS** - A + FIC(t)ION + ADOS
>
>  A section of certain diameter **inspired confidence** (7)
>   **ASSURED** - A + S + SURE + D
>
>  **Spin a plane** wheel out after revolving cylinder (6,4)
>   **BARREL ROLL** - ROLL after BARREL
>
>  Aran coil knit into **states modified by partners**? (8)
>   **CAROLINA** - (ARANCOIL)*
>
>  **Physicist** leads to departments, introducing Rutherford and colleagues (5)
>   **DIRAC** - D(epartments) I(ntroduing) R(utherford) A(nd) C(olleagues)
>
>  In a lowered state Rich **transferred data from PC** (10)
>   **DOWNLOADED** - DOWN + LOADED
>
>  Le coeur ou la raison? Which embraces **French bread**? (4)
>   **EURO** - coEUR Ou
>
>  No longer quoted or **stirred up** (7)
>   **EXCITED** - EX + CITED
>
>  Scorching goes awry -- throw away skin of ramps for **dumplings** (7)
>   **GNOCCHI** - (SCORCHING)* - R(amp)S
>
>  Thrown about violently after beheading? **It might catch on**… (4)
>   **HOOK** - (s)HOOK
>
>  … **nevertheless**, in Idaho we verify! (7)
>   **HOWEVER** - idaHO WE VERify
>
>  Jimmy, regularly tipsy, bribes **those who drink** (8)
>   **IMBIBERS** - jImMy + (BRIBES)*
>
>  Bemused, rein in cheat **regarding parental legacy** (11)
>   **INHERITANCE** - (REININCHEAT)*
>
>  Cases of importer overburden Massimo needing eager **dealer in household goods** (10)
>   **IRONMONGER** - I(mporte)R O(verburde)N M(assim)O N(eendin)G E(age)R
>
>  **Wight as an example** is given latitude and energy (4)
>   **ISLE** - IS + L(atitude) + E(nergy)
>
>  **Island** **jumper** (6)
>   **JERSEY** - ddef.
>
>  Keen to play in **middle of leg** (4)
>   **KNEE** - (KEEN)*
>
>  Ashtanga salesman embraces eastern **'pasta' type** (7)
>   **LASAGNA** - ashtANGA SALesman rev.
>
>  **Compass bar**'s head of mixology needing treacle cocktail with no recipe (8,6)
>   **MAGNETIC NEEDLE** - M + (NEEDINGTREACLE)* - R
>
>  Legendary cat and I wearing US headdress as **record of distance travelled** (10)
>   **MILEOMETER** - LEO + ME in MITER
>
>  **Italian dish** Viola cycled around Rhode Island? On the contrary! (7)
>   **RAVIOLI** - (VIOLA)* in RI
>
>  **Renounces** Frenchman's consumption of prematurely terminated zygote (7)
>   **RENEGES** - RENE'S round EG(g)
>
>  **Answer** with reference to leaders of scientific panel on dimensions (7)
>   **RESPOND** - RE + S(cientific) + P(anel) + ON + D
>
>  **Legendary persian bird** hears of diamond (3)
>   **ROC** - Rock homophone
>
>  Yes, Carter organised **Home Office, leader** (9)
>   **SECRETARY** - (YESCARTER)*
>
>  **Started tennis match** second with fierce hearts against journalist (6)
>   **SERVED** - S + (fi)ER(ce) + V + ED
>
>  Disk I erase holds **King of the Slopes**? (5)
>   **SKIER** - diSK I ERase
>
>  **Italian noodles** and changes past eight… (9)
>   **SPAGHETTI** - (PASTEIGHT)*
>
>  … **just a touch** thanks, Duke (3)
>   **TAD** - TA + D

And finally:

> Fitting the clues into the grid was straightforward. There are a few clue lengths that have only two clues. And the overlaps between pairs of those work only one way round (e.g. the 5-letter and 8-letter clues in the top-right and bottom-left). Once a few of those are in, the rest quickly follows.

Comment: Nice work!  I am very sorry about the *Compass* bar clue -- it is missing the last couple of words!  I will edit the question to be correct and you can edit your answer then also: it should have "with no recipe" at the end of it.  As for the other answer's parsing, the construction is rot13(YRB + ZR vafvqr ZVGRE).  Sorry again for not putting the full clue in for the *Compass* bar